# time validation with regex

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, time

I need to only allow times between 9am-4pm.

Currently, I have:

```
/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])[APap][mM]/
```

which works to verify the format `hh:mmPM` (not case sensitive).

I am terrible at regex, but is there a way to write it so it only allows times like:

```
9:(0-59)AM
10:(0-59)AM 
11:(0-59)AM
```

For example: it should allow `9:05AM` but not allow `8:59AM`.

Respectively, I would also need another regex for:

```
12:(0-59)PM
1:(0-59)PM 
2:(0-59)PM
3:(0-59)PM
```

For example: it should allow `3:05PM` but not allow `4:01PM`.

my current code for my validation:

```
var time = document.forms["presentation"]["presentation-time"].value;
if (!/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])[APap][mM]/.test(time)) {
    $("#timeError").show();
    $("#presentation-time").focus();
    return false;
}
else {
     $('#timeError').hide();
}
```

I was thinking of doing && in the if statement for the rest of the validation.

Comment: what is the hour format? 12 hrs or 24?

Comment: I'm going for the 12 hour format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it almost right, you just need to constraint the hours:

```
/((0?9|1[01]):([0-5][0-9])AM)|((12|0?[123]):([0-5][0-9])PM)/
```

Comment: this works perfectly. Quick question, is there a good resource for learning regex? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`/(1?[019]):([0-5][0-9])(AM)|(1?[1234]):([0-5][0-9])(PM)/` is about the only way I can think of doing it.

EDIT:

A far simpler way than forcing validation of time via regex would be to simply capture the values of the hour, minute, and time of day using backreferences, and use those to do the validation instead. It adds a bit more conditional logic after the fact, but it's far easier to read than regular expressions, in my opinion.

```
var time = document.forms['presentation']['presentation-time'].value;
var backreferences = new RegExp('(\d+):(\d+)(AM|PM)','i').test(time);
var hours = backreferences[1];
var minutes = backreferences[2];
var timeOfDay = backreferences[3];
if (!((hours >= 9 && hours <= 12 && timeOfDay === 'AM') ||
    (hours <= 4 && timeOfDay === 'PM'))) {
  $('#timeError').show();
  $('#presentation-time').focus();
  return false;
} else {
  $('#timeError').hide();
}
```

Comment: The first `1?` is a bad idea here since you're allowing `19:05AM` in the first case, or `11:10PM` in the last.

Comment: as stated before, i'm not great at regex but would something like
/(0?[9]|1[01]):([0-5][0-9])(AM)/ work for the AM portion?

based on Holt's suggestion and RevanProdigalKnight's code

Comment: @user2101171 That should work, yes.  Of course, now that I think about it, we could severely simplify the regex and just use backreferences to get the hour, minute, and time of day, and use those to validate instead of trying to do everything in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Regex will do the job:

```
/^(([0]?9|1[01]):([0-5][0-9])AM)|((12|0?[1-3]):([0-5][0-9])PM)|(0?4:00PM)$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

RegEx

```
(0?[9]:[0-5][0-9])([aA]m|[pP]m)|(0[1-3]:[0-5][0-9])([[pP]m)|(\b[1-3]:[0-5][0-9])([[pP]m)|(1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9])([aA]m)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wO4kU8/1)